# Include only a part of external file in minted

Tags: listings, minted

I am using minted package to display source code from an external file using the `inputminted` command but I don't want to display the whole file but a certain line number if possible, say from 2 to 15. Is that possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\inputminted` has two optional arguments, `firstline` and `lastline`, that do exactly as the name suggests.

In your case you would do:

```
\inputminted[firstline=2,lastline=15]{language}{file}
```

Comment: +1 for your suggestion....and for my reopen of the my question (very interesting), different `\mathcal J`.